# laravel не проходит запрос

Tags: laravel

Подскажите почему ен проходит такой запрос на создание новой записи?

```
   $userInBase = User::where('email', $$request->email)->first();
            if ($userInBase){
                $user = User::create(['email' => $request->email, 'name' => $request->email, 'role_id' => 2]);
                if ($user)
                {
                    $attributes = UsersAttributes::create(['user_id' => $user->id, 'phone' => $request->phone, 'username' => $request->name]);
                    if ($attributes)
                    {
                        return 'ok';
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Есть опечатка. Дважды написал $ перед переменной request.

User::where('email', $$request->email)->first();

Comment: это убрал, но все ровно не работает

Comment: вот что у меня подключено
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\UsersAttributes;
use App\UserSubjects;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

Comment: Попробуй получать содержимое значений используя метод $request->get('имя поля'), то есть $request->get('email') и  т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Вначале проверьте пришло ли значение

```
$email = null;
if($request->has('email')) {
  $email = $request->input('email');
}
```